# How to pass Click Events to overlapping views in framelayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-framelayout

Here I have made a *RecyclerView* , each row in list consist of frameLayout with two primary child layout (Background RelativeLayout and foreGround RelativeLayout) overlapping each other .

Using ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback ,I am swiping the foreground layout to reveal the background layout .

I am not able to get ClickEvent on any of the entities in background . Please find code

**list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- android:paddingStart="?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_list_row"
     android:paddingEnd="?listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_list_row"-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/mailSwipeMenu">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_swipe_options_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/unread_btn_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_10"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_10"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mark_unread_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_delete"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_delete"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_6"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_read_button" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/mark_unread_icon"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="@string/mark_as_unread"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/spam_btn_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_10"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_10"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/report_spam_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_delete"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_delete"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_6"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_spam_button" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/report_spam_icon"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="@string/report_spam"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/move_btn_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_10"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_10"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/move_mail_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_delete"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_delete"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_6"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_move_button" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/move_mail_icon"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="@string/move_mail"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_swipe_options_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/delete_icon"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_delete"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_delete"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_6"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_delete_button" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/delete_icon"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/delete"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_foreground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_list_row_inbox"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_10">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/message_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="72dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_list_row">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/from"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/from"
                android:textSize="@dimen/msg_text_primary"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_primary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/subject"
                android:textSize="@dimen/msg_text_secondary"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_secondary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/message"
                android:textSize="@dimen/msg_text_secondary" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/select_icon_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/icon_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width_height"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_width_height"
                    android:src="@drawable/bg_circle" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_check_white_24dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/icon_front"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon_profile"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width_height"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_width_height" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/icon_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timestamp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textColor="@color/timestamp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_timestamp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_star"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_star"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_star"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:tint="@color/icon_tint_normal" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**RecyclerItemTouchHelper.kt**

```
    open class RecyclerItemTouchHelper(dragDirs: Int, swipeDirs: Int, private val listener: RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(dragDirs, swipeDirs) {

    override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
        if (viewHolder != null) {
            val foregroundView = (viewHolder as InboxListAdapter.InboxItemHolder).viewForeground

            getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(foregroundView)
        }
    }

    override fun onChildDrawOver(c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float, dY: Float,
                        actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean) {
        val foregroundView = (viewHolder as InboxListAdapter.InboxItemHolder).viewForeground
        getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
                actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
    }

    override fun clearView(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        val foregroundView = (viewHolder as InboxListAdapter.InboxItemHolder).viewForeground
        getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView)
        listener.onForegroundViewRestored(viewHolder,viewHolder.adapterPosition)
    }

    override fun onChildDraw(c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float, dY: Float,
                    actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean) {
        val foregroundView = (viewHolder as InboxListAdapter.InboxItemHolder).viewForeground

        listener.onSwipeStart(viewHolder, if (dX < 0) ItemTouchHelper.LEFT else ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT, viewHolder.adapterPosition)
        getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX * .9F, dY,
                actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        listener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction, viewHolder.adapterPosition)
    }

    override fun convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags: Int, layoutDirection: Int): Int {
        return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection)
    }



    interface RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {
        fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int, position: Int)
        fun onSwipeStart(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int, position: Int)
        fun onForegroundViewRestored(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int)
    }
}
```

**InboxListAdapter.kt**

```
class InboxListAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<InboxListAdapter.InboxItemHolder>() {


    var mContext: Context? = null
    private var messages = mutableListOf<InboxItemModel>()
    var listener: MessageAdapterListener? = null
    private var selectedItems: SparseBooleanArray? = null
    private var animationItemsIndex: SparseBooleanArray? = null
    private var reverseAllAnimations = false
    private var currentSelectedIndex = -1

    constructor(context: Context, messages: MutableList<InboxItemModel>, listener: MessageAdapterListener) : this() {
        this.mContext = context
        this.messages = messages
        this.listener = listener
        selectedItems = SparseBooleanArray()
        animationItemsIndex = SparseBooleanArray()
    }

    inner class InboxItemHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnLongClickListener ,View.OnClickListener {
        var viewForeground : RelativeLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.view_foreground) as RelativeLayout
        var viewBackGround : RelativeLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.view_background) as RelativeLayout
        var viewLeftSwipe : RelativeLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.left_swipe_options_layout) as RelativeLayout
        var viewRightSwipe : LinearLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.right_swipe_options_layout) as LinearLayout
        var spamButtonLayout : RelativeLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.spam_btn_layout) as RelativeLayout
        var moveButtonLayout : RelativeLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.move_btn_layout) as RelativeLayout
        var unreadButtonLayout : RelativeLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.unread_btn_layout) as RelativeLayout
        var deleteImageView : ImageView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.delete_icon) as ImageView
        var from: TextView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.from) as TextView
        var subject: TextView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.txt_primary) as TextView
        var message: TextView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.txt_secondary) as TextView
        var iconText: TextView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.icon_text) as TextView
        var timestamp: TextView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.timestamp) as TextView
        var iconImp: ImageView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.icon_star) as ImageView
        var imgProfile: ImageView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.icon_profile) as ImageView
        var messageContainer: LinearLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.message_container) as LinearLayout
        var iconContainer: RelativeLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.select_icon_container) as RelativeLayout
        var iconBack: RelativeLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.icon_back) as RelativeLayout
        var iconFront: RelativeLayout = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.icon_front) as RelativeLayout

        init {
            view.setOnLongClickListener(this)
            spamButtonLayout.setOnClickListener(this)
            moveButtonLayout.setOnClickListener(this)
            unreadButtonLayout.setOnClickListener(this)
            viewLeftSwipe.setOnClickListener(this)
            deleteImageView.setOnClickListener(this)

        }

        override fun onLongClick(view: View): Boolean {
            listener!!.onRowLongClicked(adapterPosition)
            view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS)
            return true
        }

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            when(p0!!.id){
                R.id.spam_btn_layout -> listener!!.onSpamButtonClicked(adapterPosition)
                R.id.unread_btn_layout -> listener!!.onReadButtonClicked(adapterPosition)
                R.id.move_btn_layout -> listener!!.onMoveButtonClicked(adapterPosition)
                R.id.left_swipe_options_layout -> listener!!.onDeleteButtonClicked(adapterPosition)
                R.id.delete_icon -> listener!!.onDeleteButtonClicked(adapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): InboxItemHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.list_row_inbox, parent, false)

        return InboxItemHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: InboxItemHolder, position: Int) {
        val message = messages[position]

        holder.from.text = message.sender
        holder.subject.text = message.subject
        holder.message.text = message.subject
        holder.timestamp.text = message.timeStamp
        holder.itemView.isActivated = selectedItems!!.get(position, false)


[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        // apply click events
        applyClickEvents(holder, position)
    }

    private fun applyClickEvents(holder: InboxItemHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.iconContainer.setOnClickListener { listener!!.onIconClicked(position) }

        holder.iconImp.setOnClickListener { listener!!.onIconImportantClicked(position) }

        holder.messageContainer.setOnClickListener { listener!!.onMessageRowClicked(position) }

        holder.messageContainer.setOnLongClickListener { view ->
            listener!!.onRowLongClicked(position)
            view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS)
            true
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Swiping the foreground layout]

[image]

Comment: Did you get a fix for this eventually?

Comment: @OladipoOlasemo yes ..! I used ontouchEvent for background view . I have divided the view in three rect ,and on basis of whatever rect user touches ,I have corresponding callback .

Comment: can you share a sample of the code/implementation?

Comment: @OladipoOlasemo .. Posted in answer

Answer (score 2):

```
open class RecyclerItemTouchHelper(dragDirs: Int, swipeDirs: Int, private val listener: RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(dragDirs, swipeDirs) {

override fun onMove(recyclerView: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView, viewHolder: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
    return true
}

override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
    if (viewHolder != null) {
        val foregroundView = (viewHolder as InboxListAdapter.InboxItemHolder).viewForeground

        getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(foregroundView)
    }
}

override fun onChildDrawOver(c: Canvas, recyclerView: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView,
                             viewHolder: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float, dY: Float,
                             actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean) {
    val foregroundView = (viewHolder as InboxListAdapter.InboxItemHolder).viewForeground
    getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
            actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
}

override fun clearView(recyclerView: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView, viewHolder: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
    val foregroundView = (viewHolder as InboxListAdapter.InboxItemHolder).viewForeground
    getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView)
}

override fun onChildDraw(c: Canvas, recyclerView: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView,
                         viewHolder: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float, dY: Float,
                         actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean) {
    val foregroundView = (viewHolder as InboxListAdapter.InboxItemHolder).viewForeground
    getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
            actionState, isCurrentlyActive)

    listener.onChildDraw(viewHolder, viewHolder.adapterPosition, dX, dY)
}

override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
    listener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction, viewHolder.adapterPosition)
}

override fun convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags: Int, layoutDirection: Int): Int {
    return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection)
}

override fun getSwipeDirs(recyclerView: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView, viewHolder: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int {
    listener.getSwipeDirs(viewHolder)
    return super.getSwipeDirs(recyclerView, viewHolder)
}



interface RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {
    fun onSwiped(viewHolder: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int, position: Int)
    fun onChildDraw(viewHolder: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int, dX : Float, dY : Float)
    fun getSwipeDirs(viewHolder: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder)
}
}
```

// onCreatView of fragment / OnCreate of activity

```
recyclerView_inbox.setOnTouchListener { _, motionEvent ->
            if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                val point = Point(motionEvent.x.toInt(), motionEvent.y.toInt())

                if (mSwipeState == SWIPE_STATE_RIGHT) {
                    if (mItemClickRegionRect!!.contains(point.x, point.y)) {
                        when {
                            mSpamBtnClickRegionRect!!.contains(point.x, point.y) ->{}
                            mMoveBtnClickRegionRect!!.contains(point.x, point.y) -> {
                                moveMailDialog()
                            }
                            mUnreadBtnClickRegionRect!!.contains(point.x, point.y) ->{
                                markUnread()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            false
        }

        mItemTouchHelperCallback = RecyclerItemTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT, this)

        ItemTouchHelper(mItemTouchHelperCallback!!).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView_inbox)
```

// implemented callback in fragment/Activity

```
  override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int, position: Int) {
            if (viewHolder is InboxListAdapter.InboxItemHolder) {
                if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                    val item = mInboxListAdapter!!.getItem(position)
                    // mInboxListAdapter!!.removeItem(position)
                    // Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    mPresenter.deleteMail(item, mFolderName!!, mFolderId!!, 20, 0, "", mTrashfolderId, position)
            }

        mFlagSwiped = true
        mEditPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition

        val spamBtnView = viewHolder.spamButtonLayout
        val unreadBtnView = viewHolder.unreadButtonLayout
        val moveBtnView = viewHolder.moveButtonLayout


        mItemClickRegionRect = Rect(viewHolder.itemView.left,
                viewHolder.itemView.top + recyclerView_inbox.y.toInt(),
                viewHolder.itemView.right,
                viewHolder.itemView.bottom + recyclerView_inbox.y.toInt())

        mSpamBtnClickRegionRect = Rect(spamBtnView.left + mItemClickRegionRect!!.left,
                spamBtnView.top + mItemClickRegionRect!!.top,
                spamBtnView.right + mItemClickRegionRect!!.left,
                spamBtnView.bottom + mItemClickRegionRect!!.top)

        mUnreadBtnClickRegionRect = Rect(unreadBtnView.left + mItemClickRegionRect!!.left,
                unreadBtnView.top + mItemClickRegionRect!!.top,
                unreadBtnView.right + mItemClickRegionRect!!.left,
                unreadBtnView.bottom + mItemClickRegionRect!!.top)

        mMoveBtnClickRegionRect = Rect(moveBtnView.left + mItemClickRegionRect!!.left,
                moveBtnView.top + mItemClickRegionRect!!.top,
                moveBtnView.right + mItemClickRegionRect!!.left,
                moveBtnView.bottom + mItemClickRegionRect!!.top)


    }
}

override fun onChildDraw(viewHolder:RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int, dX: Float, dY: Float) {
    if (viewHolder is InboxListAdapter.InboxItemHolder) {
        if (dX >= resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels) {
            if (mSwipeState != SWIPE_STATE_RIGHT) {
                mPositionSwiped = position
                mSwipeState = SWIPE_STATE_RIGHT
                Toast.makeText(context, "SWIPE_STATE_RIGHT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } else if (dX <= -resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels) {
            if (mSwipeState != SWIPE_STATE_LEFT) {
                mSwipeState = SWIPE_STATE_LEFT
                Toast.makeText(context, "SWIPE_STATE_LEFT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } else if (dX == 0f) {
            if (mSwipeState != SWIPE_STATE_MID) {
                mSwipeState = SWIPE_STATE_MID
                Toast.makeText(context, "SWIPE_STATE_MID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        when (dX > 0) {
            true -> {
                viewHolder.viewBackGround.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.mailSwipeMenu))
                viewHolder.viewRightSwipe.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                viewHolder.viewLeftSwipe.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            false -> {
                viewHolder.viewBackGround.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.mailSwipeDelete))
                viewHolder.viewRightSwipe.visibility = View.GONE
                viewHolder.viewLeftSwipe.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun getSwipeDirs(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
    val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
    if (position != mEditPosition) {
        if (mEditPosition != -1 && mFlagSwiped) {
            mInboxListAdapter!!.notifyItemChanged(mEditPosition)
            mFlagSwiped = false
            mEditPosition = position
        }
    }
}
```